# AccessControlException on starting elastic search 5.0.1 with Java 11

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, java-11

I am getting below exception when storing indexes from elastic search 5.0.1 to NFS partition with Java 11.

Stacktrace from elastic search logs:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/globalSearchElkData/nodes/0" "write")
        at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:895) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:322) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:752) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.checkWrite(UnixPath.java:824) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:377) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:689) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:796) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:742) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:92) ~[lucene-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:20]
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41) ~[lucene-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:20]
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45) ~[lucene-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:20]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:225) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:240) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:220) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:191) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:191) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:286) [elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112) [elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103) [elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54) [elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96) [elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62) [elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80) [elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73) [elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
[2018-12-28T10:50:38,107][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
```

Note: Same setup is working fine with Java8

Comment: *access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/globalSearchElkData/nodes/0"*.. did you ensure the correct file permissions? Was this not happening on any previous JDK versions (if you've tried one)? ... Asking also because the question title reads so.

Comment: Yes the process has the correct write permissions. And the same setup is working fine with Java8.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the question about the Java version:**

The discussion in [this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/support-for-java-11/149393) is saying that version 6.x will have Java 11 support.

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/de/support/matrix#matrix_jvm) is an overview of the current supported Java versions. Java 11 is supported in version 6.5.x.

**BUT** the exception is more likly caused by the elasic process does not have the write permission on the filesystem folder in the exception message:

```
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/globalSearchElkData/nodes/0" "write")
```

Please check the permissions of the folder */globalSearchElkData/nodes/0*

Comment: The permissions of the folder /globalSearchElkData/nodes/0 is correctly set. Note that this is only observed when using a network file system.

Comment: `java.security.AccessControlException` is a specific exception type for reporting that the Java security manager rejected an operation. The class `SecurityManager` is even clearly visible in the stack trace. This has nothing to do with file system permissions or any other operating system artifact.